# Iterate over certain methods of child classes within a given parent class

Tags: python, class, parent-child

I have constructed two classes named zero_coupon_bond and coupon_bond, which both have a method called Create_random_asset, which generates random data attributes (notionals, start_date, end_date, Riskdate etc.) for both products and returns that data in a dataframe (with n rows). Now i would like to write a class called
product_collection, which inherits both classes and iterates over both child classes (there will be more products, thats why i want to do it with iteration) and gives back for each child class those data frames using the method create_random_asset. In Code:

```
class zero_coupon_bond():

    def __init__(self):
        ..........


    def create_random_asset(self,n):
        .....
        return pd.DataFrame(OrderedDict(self.columns))

class coupon_bond():

    def __init__(self):
        ..........

    def create_random_asset(self,n):
        .....
        return pd.DataFrame(OrderedDict(self.columns))
```

Then i am looking for something like:

```
class product_collection(zero_coupon_bond,coupon_bond):

    def __init__(self,n,k):
        self.n=n
        self.k=k
        self.df="empty dateframe"


    def random_data(self,n,amount_products):

               for product in childclass:
                    df.append(childclass.create_random_asset(n))
```

Anyone an idea how i could implement that properly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like inheritance is not a good choice here. You want instances from both classes

Comment: You have an idea how to efficiently collect the data for both products and join them in one dataframe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you’ve provided in the question, your `product_collection` class should neither inherit (nor be an ancestor of) your coupon classes. Instead, it should be decoupled from the `coupon_bond` classes as much as possible. That is, it should be able to recognize and iterate over any object that implements the method `create_random_asset`.

The `product_collection` class can manage an internal collection (probably a `list`) whose elements are of type `coupon_bond`.

Then your `random_data` method could be implemented like this:

```
class product_collection():
    def __init__(self):
        self.products = []

    # ...

    def random_data(self):
        df = # empty dataframe
        for p in self.products:
            df.append(p.create_random_asset())
        return df
```

To add different products to your product collection, you could implement an `add_product` method in `product_collection` that just appends a `coupon_bond` instance to the internal list of products.

```
def add_prodct(self, product):
    assert product
    self.products.append(product)
```

Comment: In that case i get an error that 'product collection' does not have the attributes needed to create the dataframes, e.g. in create random assets one row is the ID of the position, so i get :create_random_asset
    ID=self.ID(n)

AttributeError: 'product_collection' object has no attribute 'ID'

Comment: I have used your approach now, but also inherited the child bond classes, because they are parent class of another child class "fixed income products", from which i need some methods as well for the data frames and now it works..Thanks!